# Why does WolframAlpha give a strange solution set to $\lfloor a\rfloor=0$?

Tags: complex-numbers, wolfram-alpha, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I decided to go and look up the roots of $\lfloor a\rfloor$ in WolframAlpha where $a$ is any number, real or complex, and of course the interval $[0,1)$ showed up as an answer but I also got these answers as the complex solutions!

[image: complex solutions]

These numbers seem fairly random to me so now I'm curious, what on earth do these numbers represent and how did WolframAlpha come up with them?

EDIT:

Interestingly enough, I decided to type in $\lfloor a+bi\rfloor$ into WolframAlpha and it told me that it was equivalent to saying $\lfloor a\rfloor+i\lfloor b\rfloor$. The weird part about this is that that means that any complex number $a+bi$ where $a$ and $b$ are in the interval $[0,1)$ should cause $\lfloor a+bi\rfloor$ to be equal to $0$. However, the only answers that WolframAlpha give are the ones that I posted above... So what is going on here?!?!?

Also, someone in the comments mentioned that the answers appear to be $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{1}{2}i$ and $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.

Comment: They are not random but look like $\frac12+i\frac{\sqrt 3}2$ and $\frac{\sqrt 3}2+\frac12i$. What they have to do with the floor function, on the other hand ...

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the answer might look a little silly but note that [`floor(1/2+sqrt(3)*i/2)` returns zero](http://goo.gl/PHTS9j), so the result is indisputably correct.

Typically, WolframAlpha will try to classify the results to some extant.  If you just enter `x^3-x-1=0`, for example, you'll see separate pods containing a real solution and two complex solutions.  Now in your case, Mathematica is not able to solve `floor(a)=0` over the complexes using analytic tools so it falls back to a numerical search and finds the specific examples you mentioned.

Similar behavior is exhibited when we enter `round(x)=i`:

[image]

Again, `Round[-1/2+Sqrt[3]I/2]` yields `I` in Mathematica, so the result is correct. Perhaps a bit silly, but not totally unreasonable either.